# How do I get Jmol to show implicit Hydrogens?

Tags: 12.10, 32-bit, jmol

For some reason when I use Jmol it **fails to show** implicit hydrogens even when I have the box labelled, "Show Hydrogens" ticked. How do I overcome this problem? I am running **32 bit 12.10** on a **Dell Vostro 3500 laptop** with **3.7 GB RAM** and **4 2.53 GHz processors**. It has never worked for me. When I go into the unity panel menu and click "About This Computer" the pop-up box tells me I have **unknown graphics**. When I go to the page http://chemapps.stolaf.edu/jmol/jmol.php which has jmol embedded into the page I see the implicit hydrogens.

Comment: This program is quite subject specific. I suspect you will need to give a lot more information about your problem before you can expect an answer.

Comment: What sort of specifics? I have no idea what else I can tell you

Comment: In what way is it failing? When did it start happening. What version of ubuntu you are running and on what computer? Have you ever been able to get it to show hydrogens? If so, under what circumstances?

Comment: I didn't add this extra information because it's not really relevant. If it had worked before I would have specified, I told you that it just doesn't show the hydrogens, plus rarely in questions like this does the version of Ubuntu come into the question especially since this website is for the currently supported Ubuntu variants, which to my knowledge is 10.04, 12.04 and 12.10 at the moment. I will though just to make you happy

Comment: The reason it might be useful is because a) we are not yet able to read minds and b) I suspect that the problem is related to your graphics. What graphics do you have running and are the drivers installed?

Comment: I have added this information to the question

Comment: Have you looked for solutions or asked this question on the jmol-users mailing list: http://sourceforge.net/mailarchive/forum.php?forum_name=jmol-users ? I would suspect that not many regular users here have much experience with this particular software as it is somewhat specialized.

Comment: You could also file a bug with the devs if this feature has never worked for you: http://sourceforge.net/p/jmol/bugs/

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Go into the "File" menu at the top of the screen [image] and go down and select "console". In the console type, `calculate hydrogen` for individual models. If you are using PDB files to import 3D structures you can alternatively use the console code `set pdbAddHydrogens TRUE`

Comment: You should select this answer if it solved your problem.